# Map incoming JSON Object to typescript interface

Tags: typescript, object-object-mapping

Is there a way to map incoming JSON object to typescript interface?

So, let me explain. I have tried using `class-transformer`, but it does not solve my problem. In javascript, I would have used `object-mapper` to transform from source to destination. My incoming object's keys can be in upper case, lower case, with hypen or underscore, but then they map to same interface. Example

Incoming Object

```
{
  'FIRST NAME': 'John',
  'last_name' : 'Doe',
  'Email Address': 'John.Doe@example.com' 
}
```

I want to map this to

```
{
  'first_name': 'John',
  'last_name': 'Doe',
  'email_address': 'John.Doe@example.com'
}
```

The issue with `class-transformer` is I can only use one name in `Expose` that I can map to from the incoming object.

How I can solve this in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following TS features to accomplish this:

- [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)
- [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)
- [Variadic Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) with [Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) inferencing

We'll split it by using a generic `Split` type, and split by the   (space) character, replacing it with `_` (underscore). In this case we use a recursive strategy to accomplish this.

I borrowed the `Split` type from [`type-fest`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest), and inspired it my answer from [their various change case types](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest#change-case)

```js
// Taken from type-fest https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/split.d.ts
type Split<
    S extends string,
    Delimiter extends string,
> = S extends `${infer Head}${Delimiter}${infer Tail}`
    ? [Head, ...Split<Tail, Delimiter>]
    : S extends Delimiter
    ? []
    : [S];

type ConvertSpaceToUnderscore<Parts extends readonly any[], PreviousPart = never> = 
    Parts extends [`${infer FirstPart}`, ...infer RemainingParts]
    ? FirstPart extends undefined
        ? ''
            : FirstPart extends ''
                ? ConvertSpaceToUnderscore<RemainingParts, PreviousPart>
                : RemainingParts extends {length: 0} ? Lowercase<FirstPart> : `${Lowercase<FirstPart>}_${ConvertSpaceToUnderscore<RemainingParts, PreviousPart>}`
        : '';

type Convert<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
    [K in keyof T as
        K extends string ? ConvertSpaceToUnderscore<Split<K, ' '>> : never
    ]: T[K]
}
```

Then use it on your type

```js
type Input = {
  'FIRST NAME': 'John',
  'last_name' : 'Doe',
  'Email Address': 'John.Doe@example.com' 
}

type Converted = Convert<Input>
// =>
{
  first_name: "John";
  last_name: "Doe";
  email_address: "John.Doe@example.com"
}
```

See it in action on [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weXeEW)

You can add your own splitters as needed to convert any other characters.

This type then can be trivially applied to any implementation to object-to-object mapper utility as the return value.